# Java Idap Authentication for HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I want to add Idap authentication to the web applications that I developed with HTML and AngularJS.

But I don't understand how I should do it. I looked online and only found answer to how to set up IDAP in JAVA.

```
{
    String uid = "User";
    String password = "Password";
    String BASE = "ou=People,dc=objects,dc=com,dc=au";
    String userDN = "uid=" + uid + ",ou=people," + BASE;
    String HOST = "ldap://ldap.example.com:389";
    String INIT_CTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    // Setup environment for authenticating

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INIT_CTX);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, HOST);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDN);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

    try
    {
        DirContext authContext = 
            new InitialDirContext(env);

        System.out.println("I am authenticated");

    }
    catch (AuthenticationException ex)
    {

        System.out.println("authentication failed");

    }
    catch (NamingException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So the above code is just a tryout from me, and it works fine.
I will make it into a function later and i want to use it to authenticate the users that come to use my web application.

I have no idea how to do that though. I mean I know I should create a HTML page that request users to enter ID and Password. then I can use AngularJS to capture those data.

But then what?
How do I use the Java function in AngularJS or HTML? I mean once authenticated, It should jump to the index.html page.

Thanks guys, Sorry i am new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

Java runs on the backend only. You grab the username/password in Angular and POST it back to your Java application. Typically, you'd set this up with Dropwizard or Spring Boot. The backend then returns either success or failure to Angular which then sets the browser location to your index.html.

Read up on Jersey, REST and Dropwizard, there's lots of examples. Alternatively, you can run a Tomcat server and let this do the LDAP auth via container managed security - you only need to supply the LDAP info in the web.xml.

Comment: I just cant find any direct example, can you please help me?

Comment: Come on, man, I answered this 10min ago and you already give up?

Comment: I been searching around for more than 1 weeks, that's why I came to stackoverflow, sorry haha, I been through so many websites already.